# Can not reorder tabs inside a Pencil mockup builder tool

Tags: user-interface, mockups, mockup-tool

I am using the Pencil Mockup builder version 2.0.3. but now I have around 50 page tabs inside a document. and the only way to re-order the tabs is to right click on each tab and move it for only one step either left or right.

So is there a way to drag and drop the tabs as many steps as I want ? as the current process is too slow and I might change my mind on thw whole tool ?

Any advice ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem and worked it out the following way (not through Pencil itself, unfortunately): I opened the project file (*.ep) in Notepad++ and sorted the pages manually. The ep file contains xml/svg.
It's better to backup the original *.ep file first.
It helps having the XML Tools Plugin for Notepad++, to indent the xml code automatically.